# How to get the greatest difference among a list of ordered numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm

For example,

1,3,6,8,11,45,99

The interval between numbers is:

2,3,2,3,34,54

So the greatest difference is 54.

How to implement this function?

```
function get_greatest_diff($arr_of_numbers)
{}
```

Comment: Can the numbers be negative, or they're always positive?

Comment: Well, easy thing to do is to sort it first, and the greatest difference is max - min. which takes nlogn + 2 operations. Or you can find min and max in paralel and max - min will give you the same answer which will take (1.5n - 2) operations, faster.

Comment: @unknown - that's not what he's looking for, based on the example

Answer (score 2):

You got a lot of different options:

- Sort the array, then compare the first and the last element

  2. For each element, compare it to each subsequent element. Keep the highest difference in memory.
  3. Implement some kind of merge-sort, but return the difference instead of the original sorted values.

Comment: Since the question says it is already sorted, only the second option is relevant (and correct, mind you).

Comment: Well, the list is sorted already. I believe the second option you suggest is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the case where the array has less than 2 elements separately:

```
$maxDiff = -1;
for ($i = 0; $i + 1 < count($array); $i++) {
    $diff = $array[$i + 1] - $array[$i];
    if ($diff > $maxDiff)
        $maxDiff = $diff;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work for the given example, but if the numbers could be negative, it wouldn't. Perhaps the OP can clarify on this point.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? `b - a` is the distance from `a` to `b` (assuming `b > a`), no matter which sign they have: `-2 - -4 = -2 + 4 = 2`, `2 - -1 = 2 + 1 = 3`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this :

```
$greatest_diff = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr_of_numbers) - 1; $i++)
{
    $current_diff = $arr_of_numbers[$i + 1] - $arr_of_numbers[$i];
    if($current_diff > $greatest_diff){
        $greatest_diff = $current_diff;
    }
}

echo $greatest_diff;
```

Comment: ouch, please fix the code formatting. Put four spaces at the beginning of each line...